# Reclassifying with ArcPy from 0 to 1?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I am having trouble re-classing a field. I have two field one is called Rowid and one is Value.

Rowid is being reclass from 0 to 1

Value is being reclass from 1 to 0

I was able to reclass value, however, i am having trouble re-classing Rowid. Below is the script i used for Value. i am using the same for Rowid of course changing the field name and numbers.

---

```
import arcpy


#set env. settings


rasterPath = "C:/Users/Yulissa Arancibia/Desktop/Python Coding/Lesson_7/Lesson_7_Data/reclassriv"
inDEM = arcpy.Raster(rasterPath)

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#set local variables

remapList = []

remapList.append ([1,0]) <---- here for Rowid i put ([0,1])

remapRangeValues = arcpy.sa.RemapRange(remapList)

elevReclass = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(inDEM, "VALUE", remapRangeValues, "NODATA") <--- changed the field to "Rowid"

elevReclass.save("C:/Users/Yulissa Arancibia/Desktop/Python Coding/Lesson_7/Lesson_7_Data/reclassriv2")
# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

Comment: Remap range should be [[min, max, output]].. you have only two values. https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005m0000007m000000 What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi Michael, the error i am getting is : ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000864: Reclass field: The input is not within the defined domain.

ERROR 000889: Invalid field type.
Failed to execute (Reclassify).

Comment: What is your minimum and maximum for RowID? If you want to change values for RowID from 0 to 1 you should be using a remap value https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/RemapValue/005m0000007q000000/ which *does* use only two values.

Comment: Rowid value is just 0 and i have to reclass to 1. The link you sent seems helpful i will try to follow those steps. Sorry this is my first Python course. Still trying to get the hang of it!

Comment: Still seems not to work following the instructions i found in your link

Comment: remapRangeValues = arcpy.sa.RemapValue ([[0,1]]) then elevReclass = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(inDEM, "Rowid", remapRangeValues, "NODATA"), does that give any errors?

Comment: Keep getting an error: ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000864: Reclass field: The input is not within the defined domain.

ERROR 000889: Invalid field type.
Failed to execute (Reclassify).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  As people seek clarifications from you, as much as possible try to address them by revising your question using the [edit] button beneath it rather than creating a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not have time to read.

Comment: What field type is Rowid? Can you view in ArcCatalog and find the field type in the raster attribute table. Is the field called Rowid and not Row_id or something else?